# A question from oops about overload and polymorphism

Tags: c#

hi all can any one tell me why we are calling method overloading as compile time polymorphism and method overriding as run time polymorphism.

Thanks

Comment: hi pekka i'm not a proficient.. and also the question whether it makes sense or not

Answer (score 1):

In *Compile time polymorphism* the , Parameters decides which function to call .so its fixed while compilation time where in *run time polymorphism* based on the instance of a class(object) to decide which method to call. Objects are instantiated at run time so it is runtime polymorphism.

Comment: thaks arun.. i got it.. i'm new to oops

Answer (score 0):

**Method overloading**:

Means functions have same name exhibit different behaviors based on the parameter list. So compiler have full knowledge of which method to call based on param list.

**Method overriding:**

Means functions have the same name & params in a inheritance hierarchy(Virtual & override). And the method in sub type  completely altering the behavior of the parent.

So the decision is to call which method is taken by resolving the subtypes at run time.